# Unable to create Subfolder in Assets

Tags: assets

Not quite the issue some others have experienced as far as I can see.

I try to create a new Subfolder in an Assets folder (set to (777) but get the message: "Assets could not complete the requested operation." There are older Subfolders there already and I can upload fine, in fact, everything is fine.

Using Assets 2.1.4 and EE 2.6.1  - Thanks!

Comment: Simon, did you fix this or is this still an open issue? If this is till open, can you contact us at support@pixelandtonic.com and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Still an issue. Will do!